# Can I disable or prevent turning into mobile screen in Docusaurus?

Tags: responsive-design, docusaurus

I am making a document site for only PC users. So, I would like to make document site not to be changed to mobile version when adjust screen width under 996px. Is there any way to prevent navbar appearance change and item resizes? I did give my content width as 1440px (min-width) but it still resizes when I check the page on responsive dimension tool, web browser inspector.

It would be fine if there is an option to disable mobile screen in Docusaurus 2.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a meta tag that maintains the screen width, as shown below:

```html
<Head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=1440,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no,viewport-fit=cover" />
</Head>
```